# Fast way to increment an array with a given number

Tags: python, algorithm

Suppose I have a very huge array and I want to increment every element in the array by a given number. Is there a way to do this without iterating over all the elements?

I do not want to do the obvious iteration over all elements:

```
x = [ a + inc for a in x ]
```

Comment: *Is there a way to do this without iterating over all the elements?* - Do you want a constant time operation or something?

Comment: If you don't iterate over all of them, how to you modify all of them?

Comment: So there is no way u can do this better than O(n) :(

Comment: You may keep a global variable `delta` and use `delta + x[i]` instead of `x[i]`. Not sure how it will help in your case, though.

Comment: if you want speed you should consider numpy

Comment: There are O(n) changes that you want to make; how could you expect to complete them faster than O(n)?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: you mean lazy application of scalar operations?  I had the same idea, and put it in an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the fastests ways I know is by using `Numpy`:

```
from time import clock
li = range(500000)
start = clock()
li = [i+5 for i in li]
print "Time taken = %.5f" % (clock() - start)
>> Time taken = 0.06355
```

VS

```
from time import clock
import numpy as np
li = range(500000)
li = np.array(li)
start = clock()
li += 5
print "Time taken = %.5f" % (clock() - start)
>> Time taken = 0.00055
```

Note that I'm not timing the creation of the list itself and the creation of the `Numpy` array.

Answer (score 2):

No way to modify all numbers without looping over all of them. But you can wrap the collection with something that increments the number upon access.

```
>>> class OffsetCollection(object):
...     def __init__(self, collection, offset):
...         self.collection = collection
...         self.offset = offset
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         return self.collection[key] + self.offset
...
>>> a = [1 ,3, 6, 7, 9, 0, 2]
>>> b = OffsetCollection(a, 5)
>>> a[3]
7
>>> b[3]
12
```

When using numpy it might do it with a lighter operation. Assuming you use 8 bits integer on a 64 bits number it would be possible to simply add the offset to every 8 bits of the 64 bits (so 8 numbers at a time) with 1 simple addition.

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic way to update every number in an array without ... updating every number in the array. You can phrase it differently if you really hate iterators for some reason:

```
x = map(lambda i: i + 1, x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, this is the same as Wolph's answer, but he only considers addition.

Keep track of all the scalar operations to be done to every array element, and do them on the fly as elements are accessed, or next time you do something non-scalar that touches every element.

You could implement a wrapper class that lets you add and multiply arrays by scalars, and just tracked the scalars to combine multiple operations into one.  Code reading the array would go through a wrapper that did the mx+b operation.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if that is want you want, but.

There is constant time operation for this and is called [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) so

```
y = ( a + inc for a in x )
```

And now `y` is lazy generator. You can construct whole bunch of stuff this way in constant time.

What will take time, is "reconstructing" this back in list, but complexity can be reduced based on how many elements from beginning you take out.

Comment: This will almost certainly not be faster, generators are a memory optimization not speed.